# Java Excel API: Add images to the footer of excel files

Tags: java, excel, image, footer

I've got a bunch of huge excel reports created by JExcel. Now the company's styleguide has changed and somebody had the great idea to add some logos to the footer. Unfortunately, adding images to the header or footer is not possible with JExcel. As a workaround, I am currently modifying the PDF files created from the Excel files with iText and adding images to each page. The problem still remains: There is no image in the footer of the Excel file, only in the PDF file.

Has anybody an idea how to get rid of this problem? Is there any other free (?) Java Excel API that might help? I've tried Apache POI but without success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you can modify excel files with both Apache POI and JExcel why don't you use a template file already containing the logo in the footer ?

Comment: I've already tried to use a template with an image inside the footer. unfortunately, the image inside the footer (not any footer text) gets lost after writing the excel file.

Comment: I've just tried to add an image inside a footer but it isn't possible with my version of Excel (2000). What version of excel are you using ? If it's 2007 have you tried the template file method with POI and the XSSF API ? It's the only one that support excel 2007.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2003 and templates created with Excel 2003.

The problem is that JExcel and POI as well don't even allow to add anything except text to footer objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
WritableSheet s = w.createSheet("Report", 0);
BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://example.com/image.jpg"));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(input, "PNG", baos);
s.addImage(new WritableImage(0,0,input.getWidth() / CELL_DEFAULT_WIDTH, input.getHeight()       / CELL_DEFAULT_HEIGHT,baos.toByteArray()));
s.mergeCells(0,0,0,2);
```

The above code puts the image on top left corner if u need it at the bottom then just change the coordinates as per your wish.